# Mean ol' question answerers!

Tags: discussion, etiquette, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we please be a bit nicer to the noobs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs)

I'm not at all meaning to seem rude or arrogant or something like that to everyone here, but why must we all be so mean when trying to answer each other's questions?

I mean, people have the right to pick up a skill such as programming at any point in time. It's not like we aren't encouraged to ask each other for help, but a lot of people who are doing the answering seem to effectively say, "This is simple. Why aren't you getting this?" Some of it may *be* simple, but isn't it really kind of an indicator that we should make the documentation for these things a little more extensive?

Comment: What is the title referring to again?

Comment: Then again, I've always wondered why people find it difficult to actually comment code. You just write down a few thoughts related and it's bound to get you somewhere. Kind of something we should know just from school. Am I just weirdly awesome at commenting in that respect or does anyone else here agree?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicating [Could we please be a bit nicer to the noobs?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs)

Comment: I would definitely agree with that. By all means we should be. Partly hence my asking.

Answer (score 13):

Links or it didn't happen!

I see plenty of beginners getting help for very basic questions.  The snark tends to come in when it's obvious that someone hasn't made even a feeble attempt to solve a problem on their own or tell us what they've tried; or if they're clearly trying to outsource their homework assignments to us; or if the questions are so incoherent (above and beyond minor language barrier issues) that no reasonable answer is possible.

Comment: In general that would sum it up. It's just that a) I'm not getting hw on it so that can't be why they turn me down b) I am making efforts to solve the problems on my own. I do go out and look for people who have had the same problem. Maybe I just don't have the best luck in that I don't seem to find things that definitely went well.

Comment: Also you get what I'm asking here, so it's far from incoherent right? All in all it doesn't seem like I'm at fault here. It's just not reasonable to expect someone else to know that.

Comment: Unless you mention it, and that's what I'm doing.

Comment: @user: Are you the OP?  If so, I looked the profile associated with this question on SO, and saw one other question besides this one, which seemed like a decent question, and got some reasonable answers. I won't deny that there are some outright nasty people out there (as is bound to be the case in any public forum as popular as SO), but I don't see a widespread pattern of beginners being treated badly just for asking beginner questions.

Comment: @user: And personally, whenever *I* see a beginner-level question, my reaction tends to be "Holy crap, I *know* this one! <furious typing to get in before ten other people beat me to that easy, delicious, reputation>"

Comment: Yeah your probably right. All in all maybe it is just me being a bit hard on myself. I guess I shouldn't have expected it to be something else, but at least it is good to know for future reference. Thank you! What is OP though? I don't really recall what I was asking about now. lol. People gave resources though which was partly what I was after.

Comment: lol. Well this being me with one question, I clearly don't know what it's like on the other end. Maybe it's more like this with android though. The stuff Google posted was way out of date while 1.5/1.6 (one of the two) was new. Hard to believe that was only a year and half ago, but just goes to show that alot changes. It might be better now for all I know.

Comment: @user: OP="original poster".  I think you'll probably fit in fine around here...hope you stick around and keep posting.  Illegitimi non carborundam!

Comment: @user: I still don't see a link.  Most people are very polite on Stack Overflow, so you'll have to excuse our skepticism.  Generic complaints with no evidence are rarely met with sympathy here on meta.

Comment: Yeah well I've admitted to there be absolutely no basis in fact for it haven't I? That's a step in the right direction isn't it. Apart from that I sort of forgot that in general this is mainly for iPhone problems. I sort of just found out that SO is something in Actionscript. I didn't know that before. I made a mistake that's all and now I would like to move on from it.

Comment: Besides I didn't know there was a Meta Stack Overflow anyways. I was kind of just redirected here from the regular one.

Answer (score 1):

Would being extremely harsh on yourself tend to make people believe that it was one of those three reasons though? I can accept that about myself at least being a problem, and if it is reflected in what I'm saying here it might just be that that is my problem.